# match text within a file while iterating the folder structure

Tags: python, loops, docx

I'm looking to match text that's in a list I pulled from word document file using docx
I want to search my document folders files and print a match

```
import docx
import os
d = docx.Document('C:\\Users\\name\\document.docx')
tables = list(d.tables)

tbl = d.tables
drive_firmware_list = []
for table in tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        drive_firmware_list.append(row.cells[0].text)

print(drive_firmware_list)
```

I pulled the need info from the document using the above code

```
directory = ('C:\\Users\\name\\My_reports')
doc_list =[]

count = 0
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        # print (os.path.join(subdir, file))
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".docx"):
            if '2020'in filepath:# only selcting 2020 files 
                count +=1
                doc_list.append(filepath)

#use "\n" .join to print the list on seperate lines
# print('\n'.join(doc_list))

for file in doc_list:
    if 'Optimize' not in file:
        doc_list.remove(file)
print ('\n'.join(doc_list))
```

I iterated the folder and pulled all word doc files and removed the files I don't need using the above code I want to iterate doc_list against the drive_firmware_list array, and print matches. 
what would be the best way to do this considering doc_list is a list of word docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to run the code in the first sample against all the `.docx` files you gather in the second sample?

You could use a function for that:

```
import docx
import os

def extract_firmware_list(filename):
    d = docx.Document(filename)

    drive_firmware_list = []
    for table in d.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            drive_firmware_list.append(row.cells[0].text)

    return drive_firmware_list

# i'm leaving out the code to build up the doc_list

for filename in doc_list:
    print(extract_firmware_list(filename))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seened to work but just gave me an empty list like